# sphinx method return types with links

Tags: python, cython, python-sphinx

Using cython together with `-Xembedsignature=True` may yield signatures in docstrings in the form of:

```
 |  mymethod(...)
 |      MyCythonModule.mymethod(self, param1, MyCythonType param2, param3=None) -> SomeResultType
```

When generating Sphinx documentation for this using the autodoc extension something like this is the output:

```
mymethod(self, param1, MyCythonType param2, param3=None) → SomeResultType
```

The problem is that neither MyCythonType nor SomeResultType are hyperlinks in the HTML-documentation, which makes the documentation a bit suboptimal to browse through.

Sphinx gives the documentation developer the possibility to hook into the 'autodoc-process-signature' event, which is enables manipulation of the signature on the fly. The method should return a `(signature, return_annotation)` tuple. When modifying the return_annotation result to insert stuff like `SomeResultType`, or :class:SomeResultType etc, it's simply not formatted but ends up in the HTML documentation as is, without links, and with whatever was appended/prepended to the string.

I can see that the typed parameter might have to be ignored, as Python doesn't have anything like that, but getting a hyperlink for the return type to its class documentation must be possible, but I'm out of ideas.

After writing a small test case it does seem like this affects Python as well, and not just Cython:

```
class Foo(object):
        def __init__(self):
                pass

        def get_bar(self):
                """
                get_bar(self) -> Bar     <- here you see 'Bar', it will not
                                            become a hyperlink, not even if
                                            enclosed in ``

                Get `Bar` from foo       <- here you see Bar again, it will
                                            become a hyperlink

                :returns: the bar
                """
                return Bar()

class Bar(object):
        def __init__(self):
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:returns: the bar` you should try `` :class:`Bar` `` instead.

So, like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
            pass

    def get_bar(self):
            '''Get :class:`Bar` from :class:`Foo`

            :returns: the :class:`Bar`
            '''
            return Bar()


class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
            pass
```

Comment: I tried adding an `autodoc-process-signature` hook that did that:

`def process_signature(app, what, name, obj, options, sig,ret): return (signature, ":class:`XmmsResult`")`

But that still prints :class:``XmmsResult`` in the html, and not a link.

stackoverflow messes up the formatting, but you get the point I hope. It's the autodoc signature I want to modify, not adding an explicit return type at the end of the method docs.

Comment: I filed a bug ticket for this back in 2012 without any feedback:
https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/1059/ability-to-add-links-in-signatures

Comment: Ticket is now tracked at GitHub: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1059

Comment: The ticket was closed 2020-07-12.